NTP sync fails but NTP servers are reachable on Windows 10
I can't get my clock to sync in Windows 10.
When asking for a sync in either the control panel, or by doing w32tm /resync my computer sends some NTPv3 packets to pool.ntp.org (I manually set that server but it doesn't matter which server I use) and does not get a response.
However, if I do w32tm /monitor /computers:pool.ntp.org it works, and I can see in Wireshark that my computer sends NTPv1 packets, and gets a response.
However, if I connect my computer to my phone's mobile hotspot, time sync works, with NTPv3. Also, another Linux computer on the same network as my Windows 10 can sync without problems (and I see it using NTPv4).
I have tried:

Restarting Windows Time Service
Resetting Windows Time Service
Opening port 123 in the router firewall
Changing DNS settings (I use DNS-over-TLS)

and have not gotten it to work.
My router is on a double NAT configuration (i.e. Internet - Another router I don't control - My router - My PC), which can cause NTP problems, but then I don't understand how my Linux laptop can sync.
Edit 1:

NTP packet with response

NTP packet without response

Does https://superuser.com/a/1632806 (or https://superuser.com/q/1727784) answer the question?

Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and then sfc /scannow.

@harrymc Windows integrity is OK, thanks though.

@u1686_grawity Yes, I think that is what is happening here, given that I'm on a double NAT setup and it is very likely that there is a firewall somewhere I can't control. Is it possible then to use another NTP client in Windows that actually works?

Any third-party client is most likely to work, but I haven't actually tried any to recommend. (Sometimes it might be easier to run a local NTP server on a RPi or something.)

Some ISP in the chain might have blocked port 123. You might get in touch with your ISP Support.

You might also try OpenNTPD from Meinberg NTP Software Downloads.

@harrymc I get the same result with OpenNTPD. Only outbound packets in Wireshark. I have added captures of the relevant part of the packets that work and those that don't. Both seem to be on client mode.

Which is the Windows version? Was the packet that worked from Linux? Both packets are very different.

Windows 10 22H2. Yes, the packet that worked originated from Linux. I have now, however, think to have figured out what the problem is. Looking at the UDP headers, I can see that the packet that worked originated from (what I suppose is ephemeral) port 53574, while the packet that didn't work originated from port 123. So, then it makes sense. Somewhere between my computer and the NTP servers, port 123 inbound is being blocked. Now my question is, can I make OpenNTPD use an ephemeral port?

@harrymc I think to have determined that it is in fact the ISP and not my personal router blocking all traffic to all common service ports (although they answer ICMP echo requests without my permission). I guess they really do not want me running a server from home.
So, is it possible to configure OpenNTPD to use an ephemeral port instead of port 123?

According to post NTP: Use unprivileged ports, OpenNTPD doesn't use privileged ports (below 1024). I have no experience with it, so I'll wait for your experience before writing an answer to that effect.

@harrymc I can't seem to make OpenNTPD use a different port. I can't seem to find other NTP clients for Windows. I can't seem to make my router forward outgoing ports, and netsh doesn't appear to be able to create UDP tunnels. My Linux machine is ussing systemd-timesyncd, which apparently uses ephemeral ports, but, I obviously can't use systemd in Windows. I can, however, using ntpdate -u connect correctly and  set the date, but, I would like a service to do that automatically.
So, my idea is to forward the port from within Windows. Any idea on how could that be achieved?

This is extremely weird - I found several mentions of OpenNTPD being configured to use other ports but no examples on how this is done and nothing in the official documentation. Perhaps it was a feature in some port of OpenNTPD which I couldn't find. Perhaps you should do that via WSL, as Linux uses other ports.

@harrymc It looks like OpenNTPD does in fact use unprivileged ephemeral ports - just like systemd-timesyncd - but I think there is no OpenNTPD version for Windows, the link you provided appears to be a version of ntpd compiled for Windows.

Do you have the option of activating an NTP server in your router?
The FritzBox, for example, which is widely used here in Germany, has this function and then announces its own NTP server via DHCP. This could solve your problem.

@JJandke My router, as far as I know, does not offer that functionality (it's an ASUS consumer router).

Well... Yep, after some googling, it seems, that there is no such feature at Asus routers.
You could install OpenWrt, if you want to mess around...
As @u1686_grawity suggested, you could use a spare Linux Device, that's running 24/7 (Your Router) as a NTP-server.

@JJandke Installing OpenWrt is on my "list of things I should do sometime", but I don't have the time to do it right now. Thanks for the pointer tough.

As discussed in the comments, the difference is that the W32time service in Windows uses NTP port numbers in "symmetric" mode, where both the destination and source port numbers are 123, even when it is behaving as purely a client and not set up to work as a symmetric peer (it has that capability).
This means that stateless firewalls have no way to distinguish inbound replies from inbound queries, as they both arrive "to" port 123, and if the ISP has a filter that prevents you from hosting an NTP server, it will also prevent you from using NTP clients that work in this mode.
Linux NTP software usually adheres to the protocol specifications and uses an ephemeral source port in client/server mode, like most other UDP software would (the 123→123 is purely for symmetric mode). Likewise the w32tm tool works because its monitor/stripchart options cause it to generate its own NTP queries, using a regular socket bound to an ephemeral port.

If you have a Linux or BSD system that is always online, then you can use that system as your internal NTP server (very little setup is needed to make e.g. Chrony or ntpd work as a medium quality server).
This should also work for WSL2, as its kernel clock is not strictly tied to the host clock (as far as I remember) – it should be possible to run Chrony inside WSL2 as your NTP server and just tell it to not attempt to update the RTC.

If you have any place to VPN through, you might be able to use the VPN connection for NTP.

Third-party Windows NTP clients should also work – especially if local port 123 is already taken by W32time as then they have no choice but to use another local port anyway. For example, NetTime appears like it might work.

Third-party clients for protocols that are not NTP may also work, as they do not use the same UDP port. The accuracy is not as good as NTP's but might be good enough for a PC. For example, NIST publishes its nistime client which can use NTP as well as the older RFC-868 protocol.



Thank you. Appreciate your suggestions. As of right now, I have set it so that the command ntpdate -u -b pool.ntp.org is run on a regular basis on a Scheduled Task. I know is not a perfect solution, but I don't think it's a bad idea either. What dou you think about that?

It's not too bad, although if your clock drifts a lot, some programs might have issues with system clock jumping (a full NTP client would adjust it gradually). It depends on the system.
